# vscode: Unable to start debugging . The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

[image: debugging error notification]

I use the vscode to debug my code, my code can run but it can't start debugging.

my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch (GDB)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "targetArchitecture": "x86",
            "program": "${file}.exe",
            "miDebuggerPath": "D:\\VisualStudioCode\\mingw\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "args": [
                "blackkitty",
                "1221",
                "# #"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "externalConsole": true,
            "preLaunchTask": "g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error and I'm not even trying to debug, just pressing the "Run C/C++ File" button.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the .vscode file in your project directory, and then rerun it, with me it worked perfectly

Comment: Thank you very much! That did the trick for me, too!